# CurrentIndex is not updated in the Dots_Indicator PageView in flutter

Tags: flutter, viewpagerindicator, pageviews

I have been working on the PageView, and my page view is working fine. But there is one since I have used [dots_indicator 0.0.4](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/dots_indicator#-readme-tab-) for it to represent on which I'm in right now. I'm getting confused about whether how to do that. My indicator is showing up fine but the problem is in how to update the `index in the position element to update the active dots`.

I have tried every possible way to update it but, it is confusing me out. What I want are :

- When I click on the button it should change the index of the element
- When I scroll the page it should change the index

Since I have tried both of them like creating a variable named index and trying to update it's value when we hit the button. But it didn't update the value.

I don't know how we suppose to change the value when we scroll the page.

I have a `changePage()` when we hit the button to go to the next page, but the index value wasn't updating in the `DotsIndicator()`.

**CODE:**

```
class OnboardingPage extends StatelessWidget {
    final PageController controller = new PageController();
    var index = 0;

    final List<OnboardingPageItem> pages = [
       //I do have a onboarding page widget which is coming up fine
       //so this is not our concern
    ];

    PageView getPages(){
      return PageView(
        controller: this.controller,
        children: this.pages
      );
    }

    //this is a method which controls the button hit for changing the page
    changePage(BuildContext context) {
      //tried here to update the value of the index by assigning the value to it
      //index = this.controller.page.toInt()
      if (this.controller.page >= this.pages.length - 1) {
        Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/signin');
      }
      this.controller.nextPage(duration: Duration(milliseconds: 200), curve: Curves.easeIn);
    }

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return Material(
       child: Stack(children: <Widget>[
         Positioned(
           left: 24, right: 24, top: 0, bottom: 80, child: this.getPages()),
         Positioned(
           child: DotsIndicator(
             numberOfDot: 3,
             position: this.index,
             dotColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor.withOpacity(0.5),
             dotActiveSize: new Size(12.0, 12.0),
             dotActiveColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor
           ),
           bottom: 100.0,
           left: 150.0,
           right: 150.0
         ),
         Positioned(
          child: TMButton(
            text: "Next",
            onPressed: () {changePage(context);},
          ),
          bottom: 24,
          left: 24,
          right: 24
         )
     ]));
   }
}
```

**EDITS**

I have tried using **this.controller.hasClients** to update when it changes to true, but nothing works out for me. Seems like it is a static param of DotsIndicator.

```
position: this.controller.hasClients ? this.controller.page.toInt() : this.controller.initialPage;
```

The `currentIndex` remains to the initial page, and doesn't change at all.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as soon as you have a modifyable **state** (`index`) in your widget, you must not use `StatelessWidget`, but create `StatefulWidget` with a corresponding `State`. And when modifying `index` wrap it in `setState(() { index = ... ; });` this assures that your `build` method will be recalled when the state changes.

There is no hidden magic which would monitor your state. Your Widget will only rebuild if you call `setState` of a `StatefulWidget`.